# Play audio even application remove from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to play audio,

1. When app is open.
2. When app is in background.
3. When app remove from background.

I achieved 1st and 2nd point but i do not know how to do 3rd point.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: THAT NOT POSSIBLE !!!!!!!!

Comment: Why? In iPhone when we start to  play any song and then remove from background. It will continueous  play not stop.

Comment: can you show us video or link a link that apple music app playing song after kill it. iPhone music app wont playing songs if you kill the music native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple word that is not possible because there is no any API or function provide by APPLE that Apps running after KILL. So first Two step is possible we can listen songs even app in background mode. Bus how can we get functional work after app is not running mode.

Comment: My application having multiple screen. I play music .Then i redirect to different screen. My song is stop to play. 
what is the solution for this?

Comment: you need to create Separate object for playing music NSObject class that help you to make this playing globally. or you can create a audioPlaying Object in Appdelegate class and change play pause stop by using sharedIntance

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601870/play-audio-with-avaudioplayer-inside-nsobject-class